# How to organize the custom utility JS functions of my website

Tags: javascript, jquery

During the time my number of custom functions plus initialize calls of my jQuery plugins have grown causing a visual and functional mess.

**MY CUSTOM FUNCTIONS**

I am looking for a method to organize my custom functions into a library.

- should I create an object and organize them as methods?

e.g.

```
(function($) {   
    $.myCUSTOMOBJECT = {};
    $.fn.myCUSTOMOBJECT = function(settings) {
        var var1 = ...
        var var2 = ...
        var var3 = ...
        function onTextSelectionDoSomething() {...}
        function onTextClickDoSomethingElse() {...}
    }

});
```

**MY CONTRIB FUNCTIONS**

I have contrib jQuery libraries as fancybox, jcarousel, parallax

- is it recommended to mergem them into one minified file ?

Comment: [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) is a nice modular script loader. It will make everything have a nice structure, and only load the needed code.

Comment: Avoid to always import all the functions in all pages. If some are only used in one part of your site, split your toolbox. Other than that just try to keep it simple and maintainable...

Comment: Ask 10 people and you will get 10 best methods.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, I wouldn't bother storing your custom work on the jQuery namespace to begin with. I take this approach;

I will have one file like this:

```
( function () {

    var myNamespace = {
        fancybox: { ... },
        jcarousel: { ... }
    };

    window.myNamespace = myNamespace;

})();
```

Then on a per website/app basis I would use my namespace like so;

```
( function ( $, ns ) {

    $( document ).ready( function () {

        $( '.lightbox' ).on( 'click', ns.fancybox.init );

    });

})( jQuery, myNamespace );
```

The purpose of this is try to remove your *framework* from the rest of your code

Comment: What is the advantage/diff of not using the jQuery namespace?

Comment: There is no gain out of doing so, that's why. It makes your code cleaner to locate your code on *your* namespace

Answer (score 1):

#### Custom functions

I usually create a `utils` object that contains all my little useful functions like `trim` etc. I treat it a bit like a loose underscore. For all my generic functions and methods that have nothing to do with the specifics of my site or application, I will include these in a `plugins.js` file (based on the [implementation in HTML5 boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/doc/js.md)).

#### Contrib functions

I will usually include all relatively small plugins in the `plugins.js` file along with my own. Larger files that I may want to debug or update separately, that have very distinct functionality, I will keep as separate files in a `/vendor/` or `/libs/` folder. This makes it easy to swap in new versions and see if anything breaks, or swap in unminified versions with the same filenames to debug in detail, etc.

#### On minification

If you're dealing with a small enough site, where almost all the scripts are necessary on the first page, you will probably want to minify most if not all of your scripts into one for production. This shouldn't affect how you organise scripts in development though.